# Device specific display overrides possible with plist?

Tags: macos, display, plist

By "device specific" I mean is it possible to implement overrides targeted at individual displays of the same brand and model, identified by their UUID, serial number, alphanumeric serial number or similar?

I'm able to, e.g., create an override that changes the name of all monitors of a given brand and model monitor in places like MacOS's display settings.  I can't change the name of just one connected display of model X from manufacturer Y.